# amazon cloudsearch - what is the order the bulk operations executed?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-cloudsearch

i was facing in issue on bulk operations, that took a little while until amazon support gave the solution for this, so if you are facing the same problem (maybe you even didnt know there is an issue on it), so this is the answer.

Amazon API version: 2013-01-01

my problem was that i was trying to work with bulk operation on same ids, and the cloud search index was incorrect:

consider this request:

```
[{"fields": {"first_name": "yosi2"}, "type": "add", "id": 561}, {"fields": {"first_name": "yosi"}, "type": "add", "id": 561}]
```

scenario:
1. user id 561 update his name to 'yosi2' - one add operation insert to a bulk
2. user id 561 update his name to 'yosi' - one add operation insert to a bulk
3. commit the request

the result was 'yosi2' is in the cloud search index, (although the correct is 'yosi' - this was the last operation)

so what is happen here?

-- on the old API 2011-01-01 all the records on bulk had 'versioning', so updates on same id happen only if version number is bigger then the existing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to amazon:

'When performing operations on the same Id only the first operation is executed'

so as for now you need to solve this issue by yourself..

i solve it as holding an hash with the bulk ids, and if an id is already inside the bulk (in hash), then commit the bulk, and insert the id to a new bulk.